# Why does JAX-RS ignore the transient keyword

Tags: java, jax-rs, transient

In the following object:

```
class Foo implements Serializable {
    transient String bar;
    String baz;
}
```

JAX-RS will ignore the transient keyword and still serialize `bar` in responses.  To stop it being serialized in this case you need to use an annotation (i.e `@XmlTransient`).  What is the reasoning behind this requirement?  On the face of it. it seems that just the keyword should be sufficient.

In what use cases might the keyword be insufficient/improper and an annotation be required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Annotations are great because they're namespaced, allowing multiple APIs to annotate the same fields without stepping on each other's toes:

- `@XmlTransient` makes it transient to JAX-RS.
- `@JsonIgnore` makes it transient to Jackson.
- `@Expose` to make it non-transient in GSON.
- You can use none, any or all.

Unfortunately, annotations were first supported in Java 1.5 in 2004, while Serialization was added in Java 1.1 in 1997.

Since they didn't have user declarable annotations, they instead added the `transient` keyword. Had it been released today, it would undoubtedly have used its own Serialization API specific annotation instead.

JAX-RS chose to treat `transient` as if it was just another API specific annotation. This was a good call because it's easy to add another API's annotations, but it can get complex and error prone if multiple APIs try to interpret each other's annotations.

Comment: This makes sense, but I think I would have preferred to see an annotation to ignore the keyword, rather than ignoring the keyword by default.  After all, there is no reason Serialization could not be implemented as an annotation now.  Requiring a "transient" annotation for every namespace where it is applicable could lead to absurdity in the extreme case.

Comment: Maybe, but it sucks in a very specific and predictable way that is easy to understand. Your alternative might be that it's `@Transient` and then you have a `@json.IgnoreTransient`, and then you have a protobuf library that for the same convenience follows the json tags, so now it's `@protobuf.IgnoreJsonIgnoreTransient`, and then you have XML overriding it all with `@xml.ForceTransient` but your application still breaks on update because the database just added support for the xml overrides but you wanted it to use the json annotations and your bottle of vodka is gone but the pain is not

Comment: You get that either way:  Currently `@protobuf` may want to ignore JSON ignoring transient, so you then have `@protobuf.IgnoreJsonTransient`.  (but I guess you saved 6 chars).  Using a keyword (valuable or not) should be semantically transient (see what I did there?).  After all, do you want to supply an annotation for every namespace to declare that your element really is an Integer?

Comment: No, now you add `@foo.Transient` or `@bar.Transient` and there are no interactions so no having to override or override the override. And yes, I absolutely want to declare that my element is an integer for each context, because it may fit in the 52bit integer precision of JavaScript number but not in the 31bit precision part of an OCaml integer.

Comment: That would render the Java 'int' keyword is effectively meaningless when your context is not core Java.  This is counter productive, the keyword has a very specific meaning.  If JavaScript or OCaml or whoever else don't like it, they should be specifying how they treat their exceptional cases, not just ignoring the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

That's just a decision the framework designers made. It provides more flexibility to implementers at the cost of a little more complexity, although they may have had other reasons for their decision.

The flexibility that serialization, which is the original purpose of transient, can skip the field, but the field can still be populated by JAX-RS, and vice versa. In addition, it clearly separates the concerns.

Comment: And which flexibility is achieved by that?

Comment: Do you have a reference or an example of how to use this?  I'm quite literally asking for what those "other reasons" might be, because for the life of me I do not understand the value of this "flexibility".

Comment: Not really convinced it is real flexibility, but definitely source of errors. Java serialisation was a mistake and so was the `transient` modifier. IMO building further logic around it is a mistake too. If at all I would keep the logic in line with the original intent no matter if we are talking about XML or Java serialisation.

Comment: I didn't say that the flexibility was worthwhile, or that it was the reason for the decision. You asked "Why?" I'm not going to judge the decision itself...

Comment: Fair enough :) Thanks for the thoughts